# RestTemplate ConnectException Unreachable

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate, request-mapping

I don't understand this... I'm trying to catch a `java.net.ConnectException` in case my downstream API is offline. However Eclipse warns me that it's unreachable - suggesting the code cannot throw a `ConnectException`. However, it clearly can.

```
@RequestMapping("/product/{id}")
public JsonNode getProduct(@PathVariable("id") int productID, HttpServletResponse oHTTPResponse)
{
    RestTemplate oRESTTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ObjectMapper oObjMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    JsonNode oResponseRoot = oObjMapper.createObjectNode();

    try
    {
        ResponseEntity<String> oHTTPResponseEntity = oRESTTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9000/product/"+productID, String.class);
    }
    catch (ConnectException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ConnectException caught. Downstream dependency is offline");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Other Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The exception caught is:

```
Other Exception caught: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:9000/product/9": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

My downstream returns a 404 if the `productID` is not found and clearly a `ConnectException` if the downstream is offline. All I want to do is pass relevant status codes back to the browser.

How do I do that?

Comment: In your catch block with "Exception" check the type of exception, looks like the ConnectException is wrapped inside another exception...

Answer (score 5):

Catch `ResourceAccessException`. It hides `ConnectException` in `RestTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

The internal method chain of RestTemplate class handles all IOException (which is a superclass of ConnectException) and throws a new ResourceAccessException, therefore, RestTemplate methods only can catch exceptions of type ResourceAccessException or its hierarchy tree.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously by others, [RestTemplate#getForEntity()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForEntity(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object...)) calls handle `IOException` so you cannot catch it directly.

If you peek into the [ResourceAccessException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResourceAccessException.html) thrown by the `RestTemplate` instance, you can see the `cause` field has the `ConnectionException` you are looking for.

A possible approach to handle if downstream is unreachable (based on your original code):

```java
try {
    ResponseEntity<String> oHTTPResponseEntity = oRESTTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9000/product/" + productID, String.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof ConnectException) {
        System.out.println("ConnectException caught. Downstream dependency is offline");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Other Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```